# 1 How to get the amount of variance explained by each of the principle components of logistic PCA in R?

Tags: r, pca

I could get the PC scores and loading using logisticPCA from the logisticPCA package(https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/logisticPCA/logisticPCA.pdf). But I can't find a way to extract either the eigenvalues or explained variation captured by each PC.

Comment: `m = prcomp(mtcars); summary(m)`

Comment: the logistic pca command is logisticPCA(from the logistic PCA package). the outputs only have loading and score but no explained variation.

Comment: It also outputs the the proportion of deviance explained by this model, but i would like to know the explained variation captured by each PC.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue. The solution I found was to export the function that calculates logisticPCA from the package, to extract the Eigenvalues and to calculate the ratio of each component to the total sum of Eigenvalues.
The function "logisticPCA2" can then be called like in the package and the explained Variance can be extracted:

```
logisticPCA2 <- function(x, k = 2, m = 4, quiet = TRUE, partial_decomp = FALSE,
                         max_iters = 1000, conv_criteria = 1e-5, random_start = FALSE,
                         start_U, start_mu, main_effects = TRUE, validation, M, use_irlba) {
  if (!missing(M)) {
    m = M
    warning("M is depricated. Use m instead. ",
            "Using m = ", m)
  }
  if (!missing(use_irlba)) {
    partial_decomp = use_irlba
    warning("use_irlba is depricated. Use partial_decomp instead. ",
            "Using partial_decomp = ", partial_decomp)
  }
  if (partial_decomp) {
    if (!requireNamespace("RSpectra", quietly = TRUE)) {
      message("RSpectra must be installed to use partial_decomp")
      partial_decomp = FALSE
    }
  }
  
  q = as.matrix(2 * x - 1)
  missing_mat = is.na(q)
  q[is.na(q)] <- 0 # forces Z to be equal to theta when data is missing
  n = nrow(q)
  d = ncol(q)
  
  if (k >= d & partial_decomp) {
    message("k >= dimension. Setting partial_decomp = FALSE")
    partial_decomp = FALSE
    k = d
  }
  
  if (m == 0) {
    m = 4
    solve_M = TRUE
    if (!missing(validation)) {
      if (ncol(validation) != ncol(x)) {
        stop("validation does not have the same variables as x")
      }
      validation = as.matrix(validation)
      q_val = 2 * validation - 1
      q_val[is.na(q_val)] <- 0
    }
  } else {
    solve_M = FALSE
  }
  
  if (main_effects) {
    if (!missing(start_mu)) {
      mu = start_mu
    } else {
      mu = colMeans(m * q)
    }
  } else {
    mu = rep(0, d)
  }
  
  # Initialize #
  ##################
  if (!missing(start_U)) {
    U = sweep(start_U, 2, sqrt(colSums(start_U^2)), "/")
  } else if (random_start) {
    U = matrix(rnorm(d * k), d, k)
    U = qr.Q(qr(U))
  } else {
    if (partial_decomp) {
      udv = RSpectra::svds(scale(q, center = main_effects, scale = FALSE), k = k)
    } else {
      udv = svd(scale(q, center = main_effects, scale = FALSE))
    }
    U = matrix(udv$v[, 1:k], d, k)
  }
  
  # etaTeta = crossprod(eta)
  qTq = crossprod(q)
  
  loss_trace = numeric(max_iters + 1)
  eta = m * q + missing_mat * outer(rep(1, n), mu)
  theta = outer(rep(1, n), mu) + scale(eta, center = mu, scale = FALSE) %*% tcrossprod(U)
  loglike <- log_like_Bernoulli(q = q, theta = theta)
  loss_trace[1] = (-loglike) / sum(q!=0)
  ptm <- proc.time()
  
  if (!quiet) {
    cat(0, "  ", loss_trace[1], "")
    cat("0 hours elapsed\n")
  }
  
  for (i in 1:max_iters) {
    last_U = U
    last_m = m
    last_mu = mu
    
    if (solve_M) {
      if (missing(validation)) {
        Phat = inv.logit.mat(theta)
        M_slope = sum(((Phat - x) * (q %*% tcrossprod(U)))[q != 0])
        M_curve = sum((Phat * (1 - Phat) * (q %*% tcrossprod(U))^2)[q != 0])
      } else {
        lpca_obj = structure(list(mu = mu, U = U, m = m),
                             class = "lpca")
        Phat = predict(lpca_obj, newdata = validation, type = "response")
        M_slope = sum(((Phat - validation) * (q_val %*% tcrossprod(U)))[q_val != 0])
        M_curve = sum((Phat * (1 - Phat) * (q_val %*% tcrossprod(U))^2)[q_val != 0])
      }
      m = max(m - M_slope / M_curve, 0)
      
      eta = m * q + missing_mat * outer(rep(1, n), mu)
      theta = outer(rep(1, n), mu) + scale(eta, center = mu, scale = FALSE) %*% tcrossprod(U)
    }
    
    Z = as.matrix(theta + 4 * q * (1 - inv.logit.mat(q * theta)))
    if (main_effects) {
      mu = as.numeric(colMeans(Z - eta %*% tcrossprod(U)))
    }
    
    eta = m * q + missing_mat * outer(rep(1, n), mu)
    
    mat_temp = crossprod(scale(eta, center = mu, scale = FALSE), Z)
    mat_temp = mat_temp + t(mat_temp) - crossprod(eta) + n * outer(mu, mu)
    
    # RSpectra could give poor estimates of e-vectors
    # so I switch to standard eigen if it does
    repeat {
      if (partial_decomp) {
        eig = RSpectra::eigs_sym(mat_temp, k = min(k + 2, d))
      }
      if (!partial_decomp || any(eig$values[1:k] < 0)) {
        eig = eigen(mat_temp, symmetric = TRUE)
        if (!quiet & partial_decomp) {
          cat("RSpectra::eigs_sym returned negative values.\n")
        }
      }
      #####################################################
      U = matrix(eig$vectors[, 1:k], d, k)
      
      
      theta = outer(rep(1, n), mu) + scale(eta, center = mu, scale = FALSE) %*% tcrossprod(U)
      this_loglike <- log_like_Bernoulli(q = q, theta = theta)
      
      if (!partial_decomp | this_loglike >= loglike) {
        loglike = this_loglike
        break
      } else {
        partial_decomp = FALSE
        warning("RSpectra::eigs_sym was too inaccurate in iteration ", i , ". Switched to base::eigen")
      }
    }
    
    loss_trace[i + 1] = (-loglike) / sum(q!=0)
    
    if (!quiet) {
      time_elapsed = as.numeric(proc.time() - ptm)[3]
      tot_time = max_iters / i * time_elapsed
      time_remain = tot_time - time_elapsed
      cat(i, "  ", loss_trace[i + 1], "")
      cat(round(time_elapsed / 3600, 1), "hours elapsed. Max", round(time_remain / 3600, 1), "hours remain.\n")
    }
    if (i > 4) {
      # when solving for m, the monoticity does not apply
      if (solve_M) {
        if (abs(loss_trace[i] - loss_trace[i + 1]) < conv_criteria) {
          break
        }
      } else {
        if ((loss_trace[i] - loss_trace[i + 1]) < conv_criteria) {
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  # test if loss function increases
  if ((loss_trace[i + 1] - loss_trace[i]) > (1e-10)) {
    U = last_U
    mu = last_mu
    m = last_m
    i = i - 1
    
    if (!solve_M) {
      warning("Algorithm stopped because deviance increased.\nThis should not happen!")
    }
  }
  
  # calculate the null log likelihood for % deviance explained
  if (main_effects) {
    null_proportions = colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  } else {
    null_proportions = rep(0.5, d)
  }
  null_loglikes <- null_proportions * log(null_proportions) +
    (1 - null_proportions) * log(1 - null_proportions)
  null_loglike = sum((null_loglikes * colSums(q!=0))[!(null_proportions %in% c(0, 1))])
  
  eta = m * q + missing_mat * outer(rep(1, n), mu)
  
  #calculate explained variance
  total_eig = sum(eig$values[1:k])
  eig_sorted = sort(eig$values[1:k], decreasing = TRUE)
  
  explainedVariance = c()
  for (eig in eig_sorted){
    explainedVariance = append(explainedVariance, eig/total_eig)
  }
  
  object <- list(mu = mu,
                 U = U,
                 PCs = scale(eta, center = mu, scale = FALSE) %*% U,
                 explainedVariance = explainedVariance,
                 m = m,
                 M = m, # need to depricate after 0.1.1
                 iters = i,
                 loss_trace = loss_trace[1:(i + 1)],
                 prop_deviance_expl = 1 - loglike / null_loglike)
  class(object) <- "lpca"
  object
}

logpca_model = logisticPCA2(data, k = 9, m = 8)
logpca_model$explainedVariance
```